# Sharepoint 2010, Determine access to SPListItem based on a Current User

Tags: c#, security, sharepoint-2010, caml, splistitem

i am using a  CAML Queryy to get all the list items that are cotains a ContentType, but i also need to know if the Current user, has permissions to see that file.

That part i do not know how can i check it.

i use this exmpla as reference of how to get the items related to a content type.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/how-to-find-all-documents-of-a-certain-content-type

Thanks.

Comment: Try to access the resource *while impersonating the user*. SP will let you know if you are not authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default in SharePoint our code runs impersonated as the user executing the web request. Thus the items returned by the CAML query are already security trimmed. Meaning, the result set only contains items the current user is allowed to "see".

Under some circumstances you are required to execute the CAML query with system priveliges. To do so the `SPSite` object has to be opend with the system account token:

```
using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite("http://server-url", SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
{
  // open web; list; 
  // execute caml query with system account priveliges.
}
```

In that case you could check / ensure permissions on a certain list item with the method `DoesUserHavePermissions`:

```
SPListItem item = //...
if (item.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser, SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems))
{
  // futher actions if user has permission goes here.
}
```

Important to note is that you have to call the overload of the `DoesUserHavePermissions` with the `SPUser` argument. The overload without will use the "current user" of the site. Which is the system account since the site was opened with the system account token.

Comment: Other Question, i need to do the same thing, but with claims, its theres again to do this??, Thanks.

Comment: The answer above from Stefan is incorrect, as it results in an error when the page is accessed anonymous. Because `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser is null` then. Does someone have an answer addressing this problem?